# Blender crashes when I use denoiser

Tags: rendering

Blender crashes when I try to render while checking denoiser,  what can I do to still use denoiser without blender crashing?

Comment: It all depends on your render settings and the resources in your computer.  You might try using smaller tiles. Read: [Why does Denoising take up so much memory?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/why-does-denoising-take-up-so-much-memory)