# Blender quiting during render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have 32 GB ram and a rtx 2070 with 8gb vram, and am working with a 10 MB file. I am rendering a 1080X1080 at 50% and 240 samples with dnoise, and blender still quits on me during the render. It just goes to windows.
I should have plenty of memory for the movie render.
I even turned down the light paths and bounces by half.
Any suggestions on what is causing the problem. I am using 2.81 with windows 10. and using cycles with GPU compute.

The scene is very simple, the only modifier is a subdivision surface set for 2 on render and a quality of 3. Vertices are 23000, faces 21500 both rounded up to the nearest 100 it is basicly only a makehuman character with nothing else after I did some mods to it. I am not getting any errors, it exits in a blink.

Comment: I ran Blender with the dbug and it looks like it was my dnoise addon that was the causing the problem. I turned it off and it works fine.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/why-does-denoising-take-up-so-much-memory