# 2.83 - Cycles - CUDA error: Out of memory in mem_alloc_result, line 815

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When rendering in Cycles at 1080p, everything went fine until it started denoising. I then suddenly got the error: `CUDA error: Out of memory in mem_alloc_result, line 815`.

My GPU has 6GB VRAM and my computer has 24GB RAM, yet neither showed any signs of approaching the max.

Comment: The denoiser uses a lot of memory. [Why does denoising take up so much memory?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/why-does-denoising-take-up-so-much-memory)

Comment: I had to switch my viewport shading from rendered to solid to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoising the entire 1920x1080 image at once caused the out-of-memory issue. Disabling *Progressive Refine* and making the tile size reduced the number of pixels denoised at once, eliminating the issue.

[image]
[image]