# Crashing when Denoising (2.79)

Tags: denoise

Hi i am a gfx creator :)

when I am trying to denoise as soon as my tile goes transparent it just closes on me! and it happens everytime. when i dont denoise it doesnt close then it ends up noisy and grainy! :(

Just so you dont ask for info:

Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz 2.16Gz

Intalled memory: 8.00 GB (2.88 GB usable)

System type: 32-bit Operating system, x64-based processor

I have windows

Comment: Denoising uses a lot of memory. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/why-does-denoising-take-up-so-much-memory.

Comment: Why are you using a 32 bit OS? You will not be able to do much with that!